# How to rewrite an expression for only some of the variables in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Is there any way in Sympy to rewrite equations for only one of the variables. Consider the following code:

```py
>>> from sympy import symbols, sin, cos, exp, I
>>> phi, theta = symbols(["phi", "theta"])
>>> expr = (I*sin(phi) - cos(phi)) * sin(2*theta)

>>> expr.rewrite(exp) # this rewrites both theta and phi in terms of exp
I*(exp(2*I*theta) - exp(-2*I*theta))*exp(-I*phi)/2

>>> expr.simplify() # this does not simplify to exp since the exponent is -ix
(I*sin(phi) - cos(phi))*sin(2*theta)
```

What I require instead is:

```
sin(2*theta)*exp(-I*phi)
```

So, is there any way to tell Sympy that it should rewrite in terms of `exp` for only the variable `phi`, and not `theta`. I could use `replace` to achive this, but is there a "hands-free" to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `replace` is the solution here. And it's not so much the `theta` or `phi` as much as it is the fact that the sum is written as the trig expansion of `exp`. So let's target sums in the (factored) expression:

```
>>> expr.replace(lambda x:x.is_Add, lambda x:x.rewrite(exp))
-exp(-I*phi)*sin(2*theta)
```

Comment: This uses `replace`, which I wanted to avoid, but it seems to be the only way to do this. Thanks